# QGIS webmap popup links

Tags: qgis, web-mapping, popup

I have used the QGIS2Web plugin to create a Leaflet web map. I have successfully incorporated into the webmap popups 1) photos; 2) URLs which open external websites in a new tab of the browser. I now want to incorporate a similar link in the popup which opens a document (e.g. .pdf) held on my local computer in a new tab but have not been able to do this. My only experience of coding has been to copy very short sections without understanding what it actually means.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. This seems more like a pure JavaScript question which might be better researched in [so] proper. Unfortunately, understanding what your code is doing is essential to not introducing security risks for your end-users.